# How to call controller action in Laravel and run validation request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a groups table in my database and each group has a slug. I have the following routes defined last in my routes.php file so that if no other URL is matched the app checks whether the slug belongs to a group and shows the group page instead. There is also a form on the group page so the submission of this form needs to be handled as well.

```
Route::get('{slug}', ['as' => 'dynamic_route', function($slug){
    $group = \App\Group::where('slug', $slug)->first();
    if(!is_null($group)) {
        $app = app();
        $controller = $app->make('App\Http\Controllers\GroupsController');
        return $controller->callAction('view', ['slug' => $group->slug]);
    } else {
        abort(404);
    }
}]);

Route::post('{slug}', ['as' => 'dynamic_route_submit', function($slug){
    $group = \App\Group::where('slug', $slug)->first();
    if(!is_null($group)) {
        $app = app();
        $controller = $app->make('App\Http\Controllers\GroupsController');
        return $controller->callAction('handle_register', [$group->slug]);
    } else {
        abort(404);
    }
}]);
```

Here is my groups controller:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use View;
use App\Group;
use App\Lifestyle_question;
use App\Http\Requests\User\RegisterStep1Request;
use App\Http\Requests\User\RegisterStep2Request;
use Breadcrumbs;

class GroupsController extends FrontendController {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function view($slug)
    {
        $this->data['group'] = Group::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();

        $this->data['lifestyle_questions'] = Lifestyle_question::all();

        Breadcrumbs::setCurrentRoute('dynamic_route', $this->data['group']);

        return View::make('groups/view', $this->data);
    }

    function handle_register(RegisterStep1Request $request1, RegisterStep2Request $request2, $slug)
    {
        $this->data['group'] = Group::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();

        die("Validation passed");
    }
}
```

The view method works fine however when I submit the form I get the following error message:

```
ErrorException in GroupsController.php line 27:
Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\GroupsController::handle_register() must be an instance of App\Http\Requests\User\RegisterStep1Request, string given
```

I know this has to do with the parameters that are being passed to the controller method from the route definition and so I tried the following in an attempt to sort it:

```
Route::post('{slug}', ['as' => 'dynamic_route_submit', function($slug){
    $group = \App\Group::where('slug', $slug)->first();
    if(!is_null($group)) {
        $app = app();
        $controller = $app->make('App\Http\Controllers\GroupsController');
        return $controller->callAction('handle_register', [new \App\Http\Requests\User\RegisterStep1Request, new \App\Http\Requests\User\RegisterStep2Request, $group->slug]);
    } else {
        abort(404);
    }
}]);
```

This fixed the issue except the requests just didn't get triggered. How can I call this method and ensure that the requests get triggered so that the validation is run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use an anonymous function in the routing if you're going to call a controller inside of it. Declare your route like this:

`Route::post('{slug}', ['as' => 'dynamic_route_submit', 'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\GroupsController@handle_register']);`

Then in the controller handle whatever validation is necessary.

Answer (score -1):

You could try moving your request validations out of the Request classes and into private controller actions:

**`UserController.php`**

```
/**
 * Validates a Create User request
 */
protected function validateCreate()
{
    $this->validate($this->request, [
        'name'              => 'required|max:255',
        'email'             => 'required|unique:users|max:255',
        'account_types_id'  => 'required|numeric',
    ]);
}
```

So do something similar with your code and call these validation methods from within your controller action:

**`UserController.php`**

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 * @throws CreateException
 */
public function create()
{
    $this->validateCreate();
```

As an FYI you can access route parameters by name using `request()->route()->getParameter('slug')`

```
$slug = request()->route()->getParameter('slug');
$this->data['group'] = Group::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm guessing that probably would work so I may have to do it this way if I can't find another solution, I prefer keeping my validation in requests though if I can rather that cluttering up the controller if I can.